# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Failed to fetch systemd-hwe-hwdb all 249.11.3

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome, update-manager

I got an error when trying to install Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-liberation google-chrome-stable libgbm1 libu2f-udev libwayland-server0
  systemd-hwe-hwdb udev
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,453 kB/107 MB of archives.
After this operation, 351 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 fonts-liberation all 1:1.07.4-11 [822 kB]
Get:2 /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb google-chrome-stable amd64 120.0.6099.109-1 [105 MB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libwayland-server0 amd64 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1 [34.3 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libgbm1 amd64 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 [33.1 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 249.11-0ubuntu3.11 [1,557 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libu2f-udev all 1.1.10-3build2 [4,190 B]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 systemd-hwe-hwdb all 249.11.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Fetched 2,450 kB in 3s (712 kB/s)

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd-hwe/systemd-hwe-hwdb_249.11.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Reproduce:

```
sudo apt-get update
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -P /tmp
sudo apt-get install -y /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

How to fix this issue when `systemd-hwe-hwdb_249.11.3_all.deb` doesn't exist?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update` on that again.  I just looked at mine and I am running 22.04.3 and it downloads `systemd-hwe-hwdb` as version `249.11.4` and it is found in the `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64` repo

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my issue from @Terrance advice.

I replaced `archive.ubuntu.com` with `us.archive.ubuntu.com`. And replaced `apt-get` with `apt`.

```
sudo sed -i 's|http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates|http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates|g' /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt -y update

wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -P /tmp

sudo apt install -y /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```